# Collaps/Expand ul list with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd found this code (below) which collaps/expand a "ul" list

It works fine but I need that every time an "ul" is expanded all others "ul" get closed.

http://jsfiddle.net/mtCWr/2/

```
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
        <a>Rifles</a>
        <ul>
            <li>M16</li>  
            <li>MP5</li>  
            <li>AR15</li>  
            <li>M16A1</li>            
        </ul>                
    </li>

    <li>
        <a>Guns</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Magnum</li>  
            <li>Colt</li>      
        </ul>                
    </li>
</ul>​
```

JS

```
$('.list > li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following line to the click handler to close any open `ul`:

```
$('.list > li a').click(function() {
    $('.list ul:visible').hide(); // this closes any open ul
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtCWr/2/)

Comment: the beauty of jQuery :)